# How can I remove empty lines from wmic output?

Tags: windows, path, cmd, wmic

This is my string to obtain the position of TeamViewer (any version) service executable:

```
for /f "skip=1 delims=" %A in ('wmic path win32_service where "name like 'TeamViewer%'" get pathname') do set POSITION=%A
```

The problem is caused by `wmic` because it includes an empty line at the end of result (on Windows 7 command) and this is the output:

```
C:\Users\giovanni>for /f "skip=1 delims=" %A in ('wmic path win32_service where "name like 'TeamViewer%
'" get pathname') do set POSITION=%A

 :\Users\giovanni>set POSITION="C:\Program Files\TeamViewer\Version8\TeamViewer_Service.exe"

 :\Users\giovanni>set POSITION=

C:\Users\giovanni>echo %position%
ECHO enabled.
```

How I can get only the second line of the output with the correct position of the executable? (or skip the latest line, of course).

Thanks all in advance and have a nice day.
Giovanni.

This is checktv.bat:

```
for /f "skip=1 delims=" %%A in ('wmic path win32_service where "name like 'TeamViewer%'" get pathname ^| findstr /r /v "^$"') do set POSITION=%%A
echo %POSITION%
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Like this:

```
for /f "skip=1 delims=" %A in (
  'wmic path win32_service where "name like 'TeamViewer%'" get pathname ^| findstr /r /v "^$"'
) do set POSITION=%A
```

The `findstr /r /v "^$"` removes empty lines from the output.

Comment: And -I add to the request- can I include the complete string in a batch file? I need to specify something before?

Comment: If you want to use this in a batch file you have to change `%A` to `%%A`.

Comment: If i change `%A` in `%AA` the batch doesn't produce anything:  
`for /f "skip=1 delims=" %%A in ('wmic path win32_service where "name like 'TeamViewer%'" get pathname ^| findstr /r /v "^$"') do set POSITION=%%A`  
`C:\>checkteamviewer.bat  
C:\>`

Comment: Add `echo %POSITION%` at the end of the batch file.

Comment: Sorry Ansgar, I have edited my question and I have included "checktv.bat" code.

Comment: Ah, I see. You have to double the `%` in the WMI query as well: `"name like 'TeamViewer%%'"`.

Answer (score 8):

wmic blah /value | find "=" >> wherever

output will be

field=value

no extra lines

tokenize from there, delim =

Comment: Nice point. The `/VALUE` switch doesn't seem to be documented when running `wmic /?`.