# WMIC getting the grand parent in batch

Tags: batch-file, wmi, wmic

Have been able to put together the following which does work, but has a extra line at the end.

```
For /f "tokens=1,2 skip=1 delims=\" %%i IN (
  'WMIC service WHERE "name LIKE 'tomcat%%'" GET PathName'
) DO (
echo %%i\%%j
)
Pause
```

When run, we see:

- D:\tomcat
- D:\tomcat2
- \

and \ is not correct.

Comment: I would recommend PowerShell rather than batch (one line): `gwmi Win32_Service -Filter "Name LIKE 'tomcat%'" | % { $_.PathName }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap around another `for /F` loop to get rid of the Unicode-to-ANSI text conversion artefacts (orphaned carriage-return characters) left by `for /F`:

```cmd
for /F "skip=1 delims=" %%a in ('
    wmic Service where "Name LIKE 'tomcat%%'" get PathName
') do (
    for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=\" %%i in ("%%a") do (
        echo %%i\%%j
    )
)
```

The outer loop reads the full lines except the one you want to skip; the inner one parses the text.

Comment: I like this answer the best as it covers what is needed and if we were playing script golf, I think this is the winner!  I appreciate all of the inputs for this question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it in batch you can use this syntax instead. This just gives you the parent and Grandparent folder.  If you need the full path to these then add the `dp` modifiers to the FOR variable.

```
@echo off
For /f "skip=1 delims=" %%G IN ('WMIC service WHERE "name LIKE 'wdpostman'" GET PathName ^|findstr /r /V "^$"') DO (
    for %%H in ("%%~dpG\.") do set "parent=%%~nxH"
    for %%H in ("%%~dpG\..") do set "gparent=%%~nxH"
)
echo parent=%parent%
echo gparent=%gparent%
```

Just wanted to add this extra set of code to show you how you can break up the folder paths into variables.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
For /f "skip=1 delims=" %%G IN ('WMIC service WHERE "name LIKE 'wdpostman'" GET PathName ^|findstr /r /V "^$"') DO (
    set "_fpath=%%~dpG"
)
set "_fpath=%_fpath:~0,-1%"
set i=1
set "_spath!i!=%_fpath:\=" & set /A i+=1 & set "_spath!i!=%"
echo There %i% Folder(s^)
set _spath

Pause
```

Comment: I am getting the following: `The following usage of the path operator in batch-parameter
substitution is invalid: %~dpG\..`

Comment: Sorry. I missed double up the %.

Comment: Not quite..  I was just pointed to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15685816/how-can-i-remove-empty-lines-from-wmic-output from one of my co-workers..  Posting the solution now.

Comment: @Leptonator, Yes you are correct.  I was just about to add that code.  I always forget about WMIC outputting empty lines.

Comment: @Leptonator, I added an extra set of code to show you how to put each folder into a variable as well.

Comment: Here is why this will not work in this example, Tomcat is started with some switches.  Running the WMIC command we see, for results: `D:\tomcat\bin\tomcat8.exe //RS//Tomcat8`  and note: the `//RS//Tomcat8` portion.

Comment: @Leptonator, that is easily solved by using a space as a delimiter.

Comment: Or a forward slash as the delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

One of my colleagues at my work pointed me to:

[How can I remove empty lines from wmic output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15685816/how-can-i-remove-empty-lines-from-wmic-output) - and more specifically: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15686239/175063

```
For /f "tokens=1,2 skip=1 delims=\" %%i IN (
  'WMIC service WHERE "name LIKE 'tomcat%%'" GET PathName  ^| findstr /r /v "^$"'
) DO (
echo %%i\%%j
)
Pause
```

I know it is not as elegant as @Squashman's solution, but this is what I am looking for or at least similar to.

Comment: So really this should be marked as a duplicate question?

Answer (score 0):

It is my experience that PathName actually returns additional lines. When I say that I mean on top of the usual 'odd' output of WMIC commands. To be sure that your output isn't affected I would solve it using `Call`.

```bat
@Echo Off
For /F "Skip=1 Delims=" %%A In (
    '"WMIC Service Where (Name Like 'tomcat%%') Get PathName"'
) Do Call :Sub %%A
Timeout -1
GoTo :EOF

:Sub
If Not "%~1"=="" Echo(%*
```