# Command line/Script to list all users profiles in C:\users

Tags: list, batch-file, profile

I am trying to create a very simple script that will display all the User profiles in `c:\users` like:

```
%User1%
%User2%
```

I have tried using WMIC with a loop and it just hangs....

```
for /f "tokens=* skip=1" %%a in ('wmic UserAccount get Name') do (
    if not "%%a"=="" (
       
    )
)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: User profiles are not always in `C:\Users`, so the simplest way to get those is `For /D %%G In ("C:\Users\*") Do @Echo %%~nxG`. However that will return the original name used when the user account was created, not necessarily whatever their chosen user name is now. Can you please [edit] your question, to clarify exactly what you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give a try for this batch script :

```bat
@echo off
Call :WMICGET_ECHO UserAccount Name  " Name : "
Pause & Exit
::---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
rem Based on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63153964/8262102
:WMICGET_ECHO
@for /f "skip=1 delims=" %%a in ('"wmic %1 get %2"') do (@for /f "delims=" %%b in ("%%a") do echo %~3 %%~nb & set "WMICGET_VALUE=%%~nb")
goto :EOF
::---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Just be aware that this lists all user names, not those which are located in `C:\Users`, and also includes some which aren't really what you'd call 'normal' users.

Answer (score 2):

The following example, unlike that which I provided in [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66390891/command-line-script-to-list-all-users-profiles-in-c-users/66394865#comment117373763_66390891), should list only 'normal' UserNames, who have their local profile location within `C:\Users`.

By 'normal' what I mean is that it should ignore accounts like 'Default' 'Guest' and 'Admin' for example.

*Please note, as already mentioned in my fore-mentioned comment, the UserName will be correct for those currently in the system, but may not necessarily be the name used in their profile directory parent name.*

```sh
@Echo Off & SetLocal EnableExtensions
For /F Tokens^=2^ Delims^=^" %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe Path
 Win32_UserProfile Where "Special!='TRUE' And LocalPath Like 'C:\\Users\\%%'"
 Assoc:List 2^>NUL') Do For /F Tokens^=4^ Delims^=^" %%H In ('
 %SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe UserAccount Where "SID='%%G'" Assoc:List
 /ResultRole:SID 2^>NUL') Do Echo %%H
Pause
```

*You can remove the `Pause` command at the bottom of the script, if you intend to run this batch file via the CLI, (as opposed to via the GUI).*

You could also run it directly in the Command Prompt:

```sh
For /F Tokens^=2^ Delims^=^" %G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe Path Win32_UserProfile Where "Special!='TRUE' And LocalPath Like 'C:\\Users\\%'" Assoc:List 2^>NUL') Do @For /F Tokens^=4^ Delims^=^" %H In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe UserAccount Where "SID='%G'" Assoc:List /ResultRole:SID 2^>NUL') Do @Echo %H
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dir /B "%systemdrive%\users" | findstr /l /v Public
```

Comment: While providing a code-only answer may answer the question, it’s recommended to provide an explanation for any additions or edits made. That way, future readers can understand your solution. Please [edit] your answer to add context and/or an explanation to your code.