# Batch Script read a list and assign a variable to each

Tags: batch-file, variables, output

I have a script that I am writing and I am stuck.....
My script lists all of the profiles in the C:\Users folder then exports the list to a text file and the output looks like this:

```
USER1
USER2
USER3
USER4
```

I thought I knew enough to make a quick line in the script that will read the file and assign each a variable
Ex:

```
%User1%
%User2%
```

and so on for everyone in the list.

I use this to get the users from the display:

```
for /f "tokens=5" %%a in (C:\Temp\folders.txt) do set word3=%%a > "C:\Temp\Test.txt"
pause
```

But not sure how to get the %User1% to >>C:\Temp\Users.txt
It comes out blank.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What have you managed to write yourself, since receiving advice and solutions to [your almost similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66390891/6738015), more than a week ago?

Answer (score 0):

Given the apparent format of the first text file, you could set the values of `user*` using

```
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=[]" %%b IN ('FIND /n /v "" "%filename1%"') DO SET "user%%b=%%c"
SET user
```

Sadly, I can't decipher what you are attempting to do with the `for...%%a...` line.